# Using AutoLISP to select multple copies of an object one by one

Tags: autocad, autolisp

I am trying out AutoLISP for the first time.
In my AutoCAD drawing I have around 300 copies of an object spread at different places.
I want to mirror each object around a fixed axis in middle of the object.

The first roadblock that I am getting is selecting each copy of the object one by one for doing the mirroring operation.
Can anyone help me with that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain an selection using the AutoLISP [`ssget`](http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-0F37CC5E-1559-4011-B8CF-A3BA0973B2C3) function with an appropriate mode string and filter list argument permitting selection of objects whose properties meet your selection criteria.

If your selection is to be automated with no user input (for example, using the `X` mode string to query the drawing database), you will need a property by which to distinguish the target objects from other objects in the drawing - this may depend on the type of object that you are looking to select.

For example, you can filter for all objects of the same type using DXF group 0; within the same layout using DXF group 410; residing on the same layer using DXF group 8; or by other properties, such as colour, linetype, or lineweight.

Filters based on the object geometry will be dependent on the type of object that you are looking to target, for example, a selection of circles of the same radius could be acquired by filtering on DXF group 40; or standard (non-dynamic) blocks of the same name using DXF group 2.

Upon obtaining your selection, you'll then need to iterate over the selection such that the mirror operation can be performed on each object individually (since the mirror axis will be different for every object in the selection). To accomplish this, you can choose one of the methods that I describe in my tutorial on [Selection Set Processing](http://lee-mac.com/selsetprocessing.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try it out.